# how iterate over fixnum 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So, the question is: as fixnum is not a string, how i display the amount of caipirinhas on the show?

**If you iterate show this error:**

```
private method `caipirinha' called for 0:Fixnum
```

**New drink view**

```
<%= d.label :caipiriha %><%= d.number_field :caipirinha %>
```

**Show drink view**

```
<% current_user.bar.caipirinha.times  do |s|  %>
    <%= s.caipirinha %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please update your question title so that it reflects the actual problem...

Comment: Soo, what's the actual problem? What's happening and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Andrew, the problem is: i'm just looking for grab the quantity of caipirinhas that i put on db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
<% current_user.bar.caipirinha.to_i.times  do |s|  %>
  <%= s.caipirinha %>
<% end %>
```

You can use the `to_i` method to convert `caipirinha` to an integer, then call `times` on it.

Comment: thanks for your help Alex, but i think that is not a matter of convert but just to show the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<%=h s.caipirinha %>
```

----------------- edited -----------------------------

How about this then?

```
<% current_user.bar.each  do |s|  %>
  <%= s.caipirinha %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: show up this error: private method `caipirinha' called for 2:Fixnum

Comment: 3.times {|s| puts s; s.foo } this will cause the same error. The problem lies on your method "bar.caipirinha" which returns a number.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just want:

```
<%= current_user.bar.caipirinha %>
```